# WhatsApp Token Generation

Tags: token, whatsapp, whatsapi

I wanna experiment WhatsApp messaging implementation but I am stuck with **token generation** part. After surfing various platforms I found that

```
Token = MessageDigest of (
            "PdA2DJyKoUrwLw1Bg6EIhzh502dF9noR9uFCllGk" // A constant
            + $Timestamp    // WhatsApp build release time
            + $Phone_Number // Client Mobile number
         )
```

But unfortunately, I couldn't find the timestamp for every WhatsApp version that I use to login.

It would be great if anyone can tell me the way to find / calculate the timestamp of a particular WhatsApp version. Or, is there any other ways to generate the Token ?

**P.S** : I have checked my code with some old WhatsApp versions and its timestamps which I got from GitHub WhatsApp repositories and its working fine upto login. I want to login with the latest WhatsApp version but unable to get its timestamp.